# How to draw an inscribed ellipse polygon in parallelogram polygon with python

Tags: python, polygon, sympy

I am trying to draw a polygon by importing gdspy with python.
Does anyone know how to draw an inscribed ellipse polygon in parallelogram?
Could you tell me a library which can do if you know.
Although I google many time, I could not find out.
Thanks.

> I found out the solution. The blog is written in Japanese though, Easy to understand and helpful. Here, Let me link.

[enter link description here](http://yuu0720.blogspot.com/2015/06/part-ii.html)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVTay.png)

θ=1/2×atan(2(k+α×q/p)/(1-k^2-(q/p)^2-2kα×q/p))

a=sqrt[{(k×sinθ+cosθ)^2×p^2-(sinθ)^2×q^2}/{2k×sinθcosθ+(cosθ)^2-(sinθ)^2}]

b=sqrt[{-(k×cosθ-sinθ)^2×p^2+(cosθ)^2×q^2}/{2k×sinθcosθ+(cosθ)^2-(sinθ)^2}]

Comment: Here is a [mathematical paper about the subject](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0297).  It looks quite involved. See also [this geogebra discussion](https://help.geogebra.org/topic/inscribing-ellipse-in-a-parallelogram).

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you for telling the information. The material is difficult for me to understand though, It should be helpful.